# C# & JS WebSocket Some users can't connect to server

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, websocket

I'm having a really big problem at now:
I have a Server where Users can connect and send & receive messages written in C# using the **Alchemy** library but now i have got some reports from **some** users that they can't connect to the websocket server. In the Serverlog they disconnect automatically instead of connecting.

Here is the C# Code:

```
internal static bool Init(int bindPort, int maxConnections)
    {
        _Port = bindPort;
        _maxConnections = maxConnections;
        _activeConnections = new HashSet<int>();


        try
        {
            var aServer = new WebSocketServer(_Port, IPAddress.Any)
            {
                OnReceive = OnReceive,
                OnSend = OnSend,
                OnConnected = OnConnect,
                OnDisconnect = OnDisconnect,
                TimeOut = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0)
            };
            aServer.Start();
            Console.WriteLine(" [] WebSockets port: " + _Port + ".");
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" WebSocket konnte nicht geladen werden");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void SendAll(string data)
    {
        foreach(UserContext Kubbo in OnlineUsers.Keys)
        {
            Kubbo.Send(data);
        }
    }
    private static void OnConnect(UserContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            int connectionID = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < _maxConnections; i++)
            {
                if (_activeConnections.Contains(i) == false)
                {
                    connectionID = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (connectionID > 0)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("[" + connectionID + "] Verbindung " + context.ClientAddress);

                context.Send("A");
                _activeConnections.Add(connectionID);
                _acceptedConnections++;

                var me = new User { Context = context };
                OnlineUsers.Add(context, context.ClientAddress.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
    internal static void OnDisconnect(UserContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            OnlineUsers.Remove((UserContext)context);
            Console.WriteLine("[] Verbindung wurde geschloßen");
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{}");
        }

    }
```

The Javascript Code ( really simple using the normal Socket API implemented in JavaScript ):

```
 var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:38819/");
 ws.onopen = function()
 {
    ws.send("A");
    alert("Connection sucessfully opened");
 };

  ws.onclose = function()
 { 
    alert("Connection is closed..."); 
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

What OS is the server running on? For example, Windows 7 Ultimate default is 20 concurrent connections.

Comment: the OS is Windows Server 2008 PS: the initialization of the websocket server is WebSocket.Init(38819, 250); 250 is the max connection

Comment: Is your application using concurrency?

Comment: nope but i have a new mark, i have tested with 7 users, all have the same browser & version but in two users the connection is every time closing by the other 5 its working like a charm i'm really frustrated :/